# Center content in HTML table layout

Tags: css, html-email, css-tables

I created my first email template (exercise). In the beginning I did it without tables, but later I converted it to tables. Now I have a mess; I'd like to center all text and the header, but I don't know how. I've used table-align but it did not work.

Code before (divs):
https://jsbin.com/pusokiyido/edit?html%2Coutput

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>emailer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Interaktywny poradnik szybkiego startu dla Brackets.">
        
          
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        
        <style>
            
            html, body {
              /*font-size: calc 8px + (16 -8) * ((100vw - 200px) / (1200 - 200))); */
                color:white;
} 
                
                
            }
            .emailer-background {
                background:#eee;
               
                 
            }
            
            .emial-container {
                max-width: 700px;
                background: #fff;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                text-align: center; 
                margin: 0 auto;
                display:block;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin-bottom:30px;
              
                
                
            }
            
            
            .text{
                  font-size: 0,6em;
               margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right:5px;
                padding-left:5px;
                padding-right:5px;
                padding-top:20px;
                color:white !important;
            }
            .center{
                max-width: 100%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                
            } 
            .content {
                background-image: url("img/bg.jpg");
                background-color: #793985;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
            }
           
            
            
            
            
            
             .slogan h1 {
                font-size: 3vw;
                color:white;
                padding-right:10px;
                padding-left:10px;
                letter-spacing:-0.6pt;
                line-height:/*44pt*/ 2,7vw; }
            
            
            
            
            
            
            .separator {
               background-color: rgba(154, 207, 141, 0.1);
               background: rgba(154, 207, 141, 0.1);
               
                
            }
        
            /*.separator h1, h2, h3 {
                color:white !important;  */
                
            }  
            
            .separator h2 {
                font-size:1,5vw;
            }
            
            
           
              .column {
                float: left;
                width: 33.33%;
                padding: 5px;  
                
            }
            
            img {
                max-width:100%;
            }
            
            
            
            .flexcontainer {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
            padding-top:10px;
            }
         
            
            .qr, .logo {
                padding-right:10px;
                padding left:10px;
                min-width:45px;
            }
            
            
            .logo {
                max-width:80px; 
                min-width:45px;
            }
            
            .link {
               letter-spacing:10pt;
                font-size:16px !important;  
                padding-top:15px;
                padding-bottom:15px;
            }
            
            
            .koperta li:before{                 
                
                content: “\f13d”;
                font-family: “FontAwesome”;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<div  class="emailer-background">
        
        
        <div class="emial-container">
         
            <a href="#"></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="separator">
            <img src="img/heder.jpg" alt="header image">
            
                
                <div class="text"><b>usługi fotograficzne</b>: wywoływanie fotografii z każdego typu nośnika i klisz, renowacja, 
retusz zdjęć, fotografia okolicznosciowa, sesje fotograficzne studyjne i plenerowe, fotografia
 reklamowa i katalogowa, akcesoria foto, <br>ramki, albumy,  kubki, koszulki, poduszki z Twoim projektem</p>
                    <p><b>usługi poligraficzne:</b> ksero, bindowanie, drukowanie, skanowanie.    </div> 
      </div><!--separator end-->
        
            
            
           <div class="slogan">
            
            <h1>Zamrażanie chwil 
                <br>i malowanie światłem <br>
                to sztuka !  </h1>
            
            
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="slogan2">
                
                
                <div class="separator">
                <h2>Chcesz zobaczyć jak to działa?<br> 
               Przyjdź, przyjmiemy Cię z radością ! </h2>
                </div>
                
            </div><!--slogan 2 end-->
            
            <div class="flexcontainer">
            
                    
                <div class="qr">
                  <img src="img/qr.svg">
                </div>
                
                
                
                
                <div class="logo">
                  <img src="img/logo.svg">
                </div>
                
                
                
                <div class="qr">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <ul class="fa-ul">
                   
                      <li class="koperta"> Email: <br>zorza.studio@gmail.com</li>
                      <li>Tel. <b>697 625 645</b></li>
                      
                    
                    
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
                
                


            </div><!--- felx  end-->
                         
                <div class="separator">
                    <h2 class="link">facebook.com/zorza.studio</h2>
        
        </div>
           
            
            
            
            
            
            </div><!--content end-->
            
                </div><!--container end-->
                
                
                
                
               
          
            
                </div><!--background  end-->
                
                
                
               
                
                
                
                
                
        
</html>
```

After (tables)

https://jsbin.com/muzokadutu/edit?html,output

Comment: why did you convert it to tables if everything was working fine in the first example?

Comment: Because  I heard that there might be a problem with  display at some email  clients and  It's  safer  to convert it  for tables

Answer (score 0):

text-align:left/rignt/center !important ;

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **text-align: center;** in **.emial-container**.